# Navigation Drawer on the top of ActionBar / StatusBar like Android 5.0 without using AppCompact / ToolBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am trying to reskin Q-Municate and i am stuck with the Navigation Drawer Reskin task

My current Navigation Drawer looks like this
[image]

And i want my navigation Drawer as per request design  like this
[image]

I have already gone through each and every possible solutions given over StackOverFlow regarding this task, i have also followed a working tutorial given over [here](https://github.com/lemycanh/DrawerOnTopActionBar) but could not find it working

My Code is attached here

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.valyr.qalam.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.valyr.qalam.ui.main.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseLogeableActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    public static final int ID_CHATS_LIST_FRAGMENT = 0;
    public static final int ID_CONTACTS_LIST_FRAGMENT = 1;
    public static final int ID_INVITE_FRIENDS_FRAGMENT = 2;
    public static final int ID_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT = 3;
    public static final int ID_FEEDBACK_FRAGMENT = 4;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;
    private FacebookHelper facebookHelper;
    private ImportFriends importFriends;
    private GSMHelper gsmHelper;
    private boolean isNeedToOpenDialog;
    private Set<ConnectivityListener> connectivityListeners;

    public static void start(Context context) {

        PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_ON_LOGOUT, false);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (navigationDrawerFragment != null) {
            prepareMenu(menu);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (currentFragment instanceof InviteFriendsFragment) {
            currentFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else if (facebookHelper != null) {
            facebookHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void prepareMenu(Menu menu) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(!NavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen());
            menu.getItem(i).collapseActionView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case ID_CHATS_LIST_FRAGMENT:
                fragment = DialogsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case ID_CONTACTS_LIST_FRAGMENT:
                fragment = FriendsListFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case ID_INVITE_FRIENDS_FRAGMENT:
                fragment = InviteFriendsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case ID_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT:
                fragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case ID_FEEDBACK_FRAGMENT:
                fragment = FeedbackFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment instanceof ConnectivityListener) {
            connectivityListeners.add((ConnectivityListener) fragment);
        }

        setCurrentFragment(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        useDoubleBackPressed = true;
        connectivityListeners = new HashSet<>();
        gsmHelper = new GSMHelper(this);

        initNavigationDrawer();

        if (!isImportInitialized()) {
            showProgress();
            facebookHelper = new FacebookHelper(this, savedInstanceState,
                    new FacebookSessionStatusCallback());
            importFriends = new ImportFriends(MainActivity.this, facebookHelper);
            PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_SIGN_UP_INITIALIZED, false);
        }

        initBroadcastActionList();
        checkGCMRegistration();
        loadFriendsList();

        initVideoChat();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        connectivityListeners.clear();
    }

    public void removeConnectivityListener(ConnectivityListener listener) {
        connectivityListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void initVideoChat() {
        QBInitVideoChatCommand.start(this, CallActivity.class);
    }

    private boolean isImportInitialized() {
        PrefsHelper prefsHelper = PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper();
        return prefsHelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_IMPORT_INITIALIZED, false);
    }

    private void initBroadcastActionList() {
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOAD_CHATS_DIALOGS_SUCCESS_ACTION, new LoadDialogsSuccessAction());
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOAD_FRIENDS_SUCCESS_ACTION, new LoadFriendsSuccessAction());
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOAD_FRIENDS_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOAD_CHATS_DIALOGS_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.IMPORT_FRIENDS_SUCCESS_ACTION, new ImportFriendsSuccessAction());
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.IMPORT_FRIENDS_FAIL_ACTION, new ImportFriendsFailAction());
        addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOGIN_AND_JOIN_CHATS_SUCCESS_ACTION, new LoginAndJoinChatsSuccessAction());
    }

    private void initNavigationDrawer() {
        navigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.navigation_drawer);
        navigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(
                R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    private void checkGCMRegistration() {
        if (gsmHelper.checkPlayServices()) {
            if (!gsmHelper.isDeviceRegisteredWithUser(AppSession.getSession().getUser())) {
                gsmHelper.registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }

    private void loadFriendsList() {
        QBLoadFriendListCommand.start(this);
    }

    private void loadChatsDialogs() {
        QBLoadDialogsCommand.start(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gsmHelper.checkPlayServices();
        showActionBarProgress();
        checkVisibilityProgressBars();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFailAction(String action) {
        hideActionBarProgress();
        hideProgress();
        if (QBServiceConsts.LOAD_FRIENDS_FAIL_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            loadChatsDialogs();
        }
    }

    private void checkVisibilityProgressBars() {
        isNeedToOpenDialog = PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().getPref(
                PrefsHelper.PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_NEED_TO_OPEN_DIALOG, false);
        if (isJoinedToDialogs()) {
            hideActionBarProgress();
        }
        if (isNeedToOpenDialog && !isJoinedToDialogs()) {
            hideActionBarProgress();
            showProgress();
        }
    }

    private boolean isJoinedToDialogs() {
        PrefsHelper prefsHelper = PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper();
        return prefsHelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_JOINED_TO_ALL_DIALOGS, false);
    }

    private void startDialog() {
        PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_NEED_TO_OPEN_DIALOG, false);
        String dialogId = PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_DIALOG_ID, null);
        long userId = PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_PUSH_MESSAGE_USER_ID,
                ConstsCore.NOT_INITIALIZED_VALUE);
        QBDialog dialog = ChatDatabaseManager.getDialogByDialogId(this, dialogId);
        if (dialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PRIVATE) {
            startPrivateChatActivity(dialog, userId);
        } else {
            startGroupChatActivity(dialog);
        }
    }

    private void startPrivateChatActivity(QBDialog dialog, long userId) {
        User occupantUser = UsersDatabaseManager.getUserById(this, userId);
        if (occupantUser != null && userId != ConstsCore.ZERO_INT_VALUE) {
            PrivateDialogActivity.start(this, occupantUser, dialog);
        }
    }

    private void importFriendsFinished() {
        PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_IMPORT_INITIALIZED, true);
        hideProgress();
    }

    private void startGroupChatActivity(QBDialog dialog) {
        GroupDialogActivity.start(this, dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionChange(boolean isConnected) {
        super.onConnectionChange(isConnected);
        for (ConnectivityListener listener : connectivityListeners) {
            listener.onConnectionChange(isConnected);
        }

        if (currentFragment instanceof FriendsListFragment) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }

    private class LoadDialogsSuccessAction implements Command {

        @Override
        public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
            hideActionBarProgress();
            hideProgress();

            if (isNeedToOpenDialog) {
                startDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    private class FacebookSessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                importFriends.startGetFriendsListTask(true);
            } else if (!(!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) && !isImportInitialized()) {
                importFriends.startGetFriendsListTask(false);
                hideProgress();
            }
        }
    }

    private class LoginAndJoinChatsSuccessAction implements Command {

        @Override
        public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
            loadChatsDialogs();
        }
    }

    private class LoadFriendsSuccessAction implements Command {

        @Override
        public void execute(Bundle bundle) throws Exception {
            loadChatsDialogs();
        }
    }

    private class ImportFriendsSuccessAction implements Command {

        @Override
        public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
            importFriendsFinished();
        }
    }

    private class ImportFriendsFailAction implements Command {

        @Override
        public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
            importFriendsFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.Java**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private static View fragmentContainerView;
    private Resources resources;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private TextView fullNameTextView;
    private ImageButton logoutButton;

    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks navigationDrawerCallbacks;
    private NavigationDrawerCounterListener navigationDrawerCounterListener;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private int currentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean fromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean userLearnedDrawer;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter navigationDrawerAdapter;
    private BroadcastReceiver countUnreadDialogsBroadcastReceiver;

    public static boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return drawerLayout != null && drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(fragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        resources = getResources();

        initPrefValues();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            fromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        selectItem(currentSelectedPosition);

        initLocalBroadcastManagers();
    }

    private void initLocalBroadcastManagers() {
        countUnreadDialogsBroadcastReceiver = new CountUnreadDialogsBroadcastReceiver();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(baseActivity).registerReceiver(countUnreadDialogsBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(QBServiceConsts.GOT_CHAT_MESSAGE));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        initUI(rootView);
        initListeners();
        initNavigationAdapter();

        drawerListView.setItemChecked(currentSelectedPosition, true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        navigationDrawerCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        baseActivity.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        QBUser user = AppSession.getSession().getUser();
        if (user != null) {
            fullNameTextView.setText(user.getFullName());
        }
        addActions();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, currentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        navigationDrawerCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, final DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        fragmentContainerView = baseActivity.findViewById(fragmentId);
        NavigationDrawerFragment.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = baseActivity.getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        drawerToggle = new QMActionBarDrawerToggle(baseActivity, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.nvd_open, R.string.nvd_close);

        if (!userLearnedDrawer && !fromSavedInstanceState) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(fragmentContainerView);
        }

        drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    private void initPrefValues() {
        PrefsHelper prefsHelper = PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper();
        userLearnedDrawer = prefsHelper.getPref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        // Set base value of droverLayout as opposite to userLearnerDrawer
        // Made it for next behaviour: if drawer will be opened then we shouldn't show croutons
        prefsHelper.savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_CROUTONS_DISABLED, !userLearnedDrawer);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        currentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (drawerListView != null) {
            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (drawerLayout != null) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(fragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (navigationDrawerCallbacks != null) {
            navigationDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    private void initNavigationAdapter() {
        navigationDrawerAdapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(baseActivity, getNavigationDrawerItems());
        drawerListView.setAdapter(navigationDrawerAdapter);
        navigationDrawerCounterListener = navigationDrawerAdapter;
    }

    private void initUI(View rootView) {
        drawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_listview);
        logoutButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logout_imagebutton);
        fullNameTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fullname_textview);

    }

    private void initListeners() {
        drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
    }


    private List<String> getNavigationDrawerItems() {
        String[] itemsArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.nvd_items_array);
        return Arrays.asList(itemsArray);
    }

    private void logout() {
        ConfirmDialog dialog = ConfirmDialog.newInstance(R.string.dlg_logout, R.string.dlg_confirm);
        dialog.setPositiveButton(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Stop porcess push notifications after logout
                PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_ON_LOGOUT, true);

                // Start clear messages that was not sent
                ChatDatabaseManager.deleteAllNotSendMessages(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                baseActivity.showProgress();
                FacebookHelper.logout();

                // Clear crouton queue
                Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();

                QBLogoutCommand.start(baseActivity);
            }
        });
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
    }

    private void addActions() {
        baseActivity.addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOGOUT_SUCCESS_ACTION, new LogoutSuccessAction());
        baseActivity.addAction(QBServiceConsts.LOGOUT_FAIL_ACTION, failAction);
        baseActivity.updateBroadcastActionList();
    }

    private void saveUserLearnedDrawer() {
        PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true);
    }

    private int getCountUnreadDialogs() {
        return ChatDatabaseManager.getCountUnreadDialogs(baseActivity);
    }

    public interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }

    public interface NavigationDrawerCounterListener {

        void onUpdateCountUnreadDialogs(int count);
    }

    private class CountUnreadDialogsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                navigationDrawerCounterListener.onUpdateCountUnreadDialogs(getCountUnreadDialogs());
            }
        }
    }

    private class QMActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public QMActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int drawerImageRes,
                                       int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
            super(activity, drawerLayout, drawerImageRes, openDrawerContentDescRes,
                    closeDrawerContentDescRes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            // Clear croutons
            PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_CROUTONS_DISABLED, true);
            Crouton.clearCroutonsForActivity(getActivity());

            baseActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();

            if (!userLearnedDrawer) {
                userLearnedDrawer = true;
                saveUserLearnedDrawer();
            }

            navigationDrawerCounterListener.onUpdateCountUnreadDialogs(getCountUnreadDialogs());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            baseActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
            PrefsHelper.getPrefsHelper().savePref(PrefsHelper.PREF_CROUTONS_DISABLED, false);
        }
    }

    private class LogoutSuccessAction implements Command {

        @Override
        public void execute(Bundle bundle) {
            LandingActivity.start(baseActivity);
            baseActivity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linearlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        tools:context="com.sample.app.NavigationDrawerFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/footer_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <com.valyr.qalam.utils.ArabicTextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname_textview"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/link_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/logout_imagebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/button_general_selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The theme , and actionbar are closely attached with everything, so i cant touch anything from styles, but i really need a trick to make it done. Please help

**NOTE:** This question is not at all possible duplicate becuase all the solutions given here are using AppCompact and Toolbar, Please read the question thoroughly before downvoting

Comment: try removing  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from activity_main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular `Activity`, the `ActionBar` is part of an overlay `View` that is the only direct child of the `Window`'s `DecorView`. You can remove this child from the `DecorView`, inflate the `activity_main` main layout into the `DecorView`, and then add the overlay `View` to the `DrawerLayout`'s `FrameLayout`, effectively putting the drawer on top of everything.

In order to avoid making changes to the `BaseLogeableActivity` class, we'll need to change the ID of the `DrawerLayout`'s `FrameLayout`, and ensure a Resource ID of `container` exists to assign to the dynamically created `FrameLayout` that will hold the `Fragment`s.

Create the Resource ID of `container`, if necessary:

```
<item type="id" name="container" />
```

Change the ID of the main layout's `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The cleanest way to add the `View` juggling code is probably to just override `MainActivity`'s `setContentView()` method, like so:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    View overlayView = decorView.getChildAt(0);

    decorView.removeView(overlayView);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, decorView, true);

    FrameLayout overlayContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay_container);
    overlayContainer.addView(overlayView);

    FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(this);
    container.setId(R.id.container);

    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) overlayView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    content.addView(container);
}
```

And finally, if you want your `Activity` to cover the Status Bar, add the following attribute setting to its theme:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Or, since you can't change the theme, call the following before the  `setContentView()` call:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: your solution worked like charm and its currently looking like that

https://www.dropbox.com/s/73ysf8mv1pde52g/Screenshot_2016-02-03-00-49-41.png?dl=0

i want a little more help, i want to make the drawer go over statusbar too. i cant even touch the theme in styles, any trick? you save my life man

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to do that programmatically instead.

Comment: unfortunitely...it made the whole activity full screen, rather making the drawer to touch the top..anyways, you did a fantastic job..thanks is just a small word to say back